# Azure Function Unable to get Azure Function URL

Tags: azure-functions

I have deployed couple of azure function to a particular resource group. Functions are for blob trigger and queue trigger. They deployment is done in packaged mode. When I try to get the URL for the function the link for **Get Function URL** is greyed out. I also checked in the Code + Test tab and there is no button for "Get Function URL".

Could anyone please suggest what might be wrong?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS5xB.png)

Thanks.
SandeepG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your functions are `blob trigger` and `queue trigger`, then there is no URL for them.

You can get URL of functions which are using an **HTTP Trigger**, because these are the functions that can get called directly via HTTP.